# How to know the version of RPM during installation

Tags: unix, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have created a script for deployment. During the `pre` script, is it possible to know whats the version of the rpm I am deploying.

I want to create a backup file with the version of the RPM (in its name) so that i can trace back the version of the RPM file.

Comment: Answer available at http://superuser.com/questions/348200/how-to-know-the-version-of-rpm-during-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define some variables at the top of your spec file, and then use them in both the tags section and the pre script.

```
%define version <your-version>
%define relver <your-relver>

Version: %{version}
Release: %{relver}

%pre
/bin/cp your-file your-file.%{version}-%{relver}
```

You can verify the script will do the expected copy by querying the scripts in the RPM:

```
rpm -qp --scripts <path-to-your-rpm>/<your-rpm-name>.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also you can refer to the link given in my comments.